# Unexplainable extra line in <pre> in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        tr{vertical-align: top;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function ready() {
                s = '';
                t = '';
                for(var i=1; i<=450; ++i)
                {
                    s += i + '\n';
                    t += i + '\r\n';
                }

                document.getElementById("numbers1").innerHTML = "<pre><code>"+s+"</code></pre>";
                document.getElementById("numbers2").innerHTML = "<pre><code>"+t+"</code></pre>";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="wrap"><tr>
            <td id="numbers1"></td>
            <td id="numbers2"></td>
        </tr></table>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ready();
    </script>
</html>
```

In IE9, when rendered in IE9 Standards mode (the default for the above HTML) there is a blank line in the right column between numbers 428 and 429 (see pic)

[image: sample]

This is only in IE, and only in full IE9 Standards mode.

Can anyone explain this very odd behavior? Why only at that line? If it was every line, I could understand that it was showing `\r\n` as 2 line breaks.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K2SUU/

Comment: Using a mac, on windows 7 VM IE9, did not see this issue

Comment: I am on Windows 8, IE10 but when I view the page in Browser Mode: IE9 and Document Mode: IE9 standards, I don't see this issue.

Comment: I can reproduce it on native Windows 7 IE9.

Comment: @Harry Yes, always the same line. I  am on a native Win7-64 IE9.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a `<code>` tag inside a `<pre>` tag? Why not just style the `<code>` tag with `white-space:pre`? Same effect; no unnecessary markup.

Answer (score 0):

This must be some kind of IE9 rendering bug with the way you are setting the innerHTML. If I move the `<pre><code>` wrapper to the HTML and only use innerHTML to set the text, the problem disappears:

```
<table id="wrap"><tr>
    <td><pre><code id="numbers1"></code></pre></td>
    <td><pre><code id="numbers2"></code></pre></td>
</tr></table>
```

...

```
document.getElementById("numbers1").innerHTML = s;
document.getElementById("numbers2").innerHTML = t;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K2SUU/1/

You are right, though, it does seem to be unexplainable. The comments on your question suggest it only happens in specific versions of IE9. Mine is 9.0.8112.16421 according to the About Internet Explorer dialog box.

Comment: That is my exact version, too

Comment: It just happens at a different line now. Now it is at 1550

Comment: @Harry using the code in this answer and displaying numbers until 1560, the gap is now at 1550. If I display from 5 to 1560 instead of from 1, the gap is at 1552! If I go from 20 to 1580, there is no gap! I am totally at a loss

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that. Even if I remove the `<code>` and `<pre>` tags entirely and set the style to `td { white-space: pre; }` it happens at line 1550. It really looks like a white-space rendering bug now.